# How to mock an ImageField in Sitecore using nSubstitute and xUnit

Tags: sitecore-api, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I am in the process of setting up some unit tests for a Sitecore project (using this guide as a starting point: https://www.codeflood.net/blog/2020/05/17/logicless-view-itemless-model/)

I have come across a problem when trying to mock returning an ImageField.

This is the method I would like to test:

```
public string GetImageUrl(Item item, string fieldName, MediaUrlBuilderOptions options = null)
{
  if (item == null)
    return String.Empty;

  if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldName))
    return String.Empty;

  var imgField = (ImageField)item.Fields[fieldName];

  if (imgField != null && imgField.MediaItem != null)
  {
    return (options != null) ?
      HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(_mediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imgField.MediaItem, options)) :
      HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(_mediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imgField.MediaItem));
  }

  return String.Empty;
}
```

The code I have so far works to some degree, when I make the call for **item.Fields[fieldName]**, it returns the raw value
< image mediaid='{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012}' />  which casts into an ImageField. However, the MediaItem property of this ImageField is always null, thus I cant proceed to mock calling getMediaUrl.

```
[Fact]
public void GetImageUrl_KnownFieldName_ReturnsValue()
{
    // arrange
    var item = CreateItem();
    SetItemField(item, "Some Known Field", "<image mediaid='{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012}' />");

    var mediaManager = Substitute.For<BaseMediaManager>();
    var sut = new ImageTaxonomy(mediaManager);

    // act
    var results = sut.GetImageUrl(item, "Some Known Field");

    // assert
    Xunit.Assert.Equal("Desired value", results);
}

private Item CreateItem()
{
    var database = Substitute.For<Database>();

    var mediaItem = Substitute.For<Item>(ID.NewID, ItemData.Empty, database);
    database.GetItem(new ID("12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012")).Returns(mediaItem);

    var item = Substitute.For<Item>(ID.NewID, ItemData.Empty, database);
    var fields = Substitute.For<FieldCollection>(item);
    item.Fields.Returns(fields);

    return item;
}
private void SetItemField(Item item, string fieldName, string fieldValue)
{
    var field = Substitute.For<Field>(ID.NewID, item);
    field.Value = fieldValue;
    field.Database.Returns(item.Database);
    item.Fields[fieldName].Returns(field);
}
```

As you can see I tried mocking the call to database.GetItem(), with the intent of returning the desired mediaItem, but that didnt do the trick.

Any advice on how to proceed would be much appreciated.

**EDIT: Updated Solution**
This is the updated code with correctly mocked media item.
*Note: there is still an issue with my use of BaseMediaManager, but that will be focus of another question. ([How to mock MediaManager in Sitecore using nSubstitute and xUnit](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30703/how-to-mock-mediamanager-in-sitecore-using-nsubstitute-and-xunit))*

```
public void GetImageUrl_KnownFieldName_ReturnsValue()
{
    // arrange
    var database = Substitute.For<Database>();

    var item = CreateItem(database);
    SetItemField(item, "Some Known Field", $"<image mediaid='{mediaItemIDString}' />");

    var mediaItem = CreateMediaItem(database);
    database.GetItem(mediaItemID, Arg.Any<Language>(), Sitecore.Data.Version.Latest).Returns(mediaItem);

    var mediaManager = Substitute.For<BaseMediaManager>();
    mediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem).Returns("/a/path/to/an/image.jpg");

    var sut = new ImageTaxonomy(mediaManager);

    // act
    var results = sut.GetImageUrl(item, "Some Known Field");

    // assert
    Xunit.Assert.Equal("/a/path/to/an/image.jpg", results);
}

private Item CreateItem(Database database = null)
{
    var item = Substitute.For<Item>(ID.NewID, ItemData.Empty, database);
    var fields = Substitute.For<FieldCollection>(item);
    item.Fields.Returns(fields);
    return item;
}
private Item CreateMediaItem(Database database = null)
{
    var definition = new ItemDefinition(mediaItemID, "Mock Media Item", ID.Null, ID.Null);
    var data = new ItemData(definition, Language.Current, Sitecore.Data.Version.First, new FieldList());
    var mediaItem = new Item(mediaItemID, data, database);
    return mediaItem;
}
private void SetItemField(Item item, string fieldName, string fieldValue)
{
    var field = Substitute.For<Field>(ID.NewID, item);
    field.Value = fieldValue;
    field.Database.Returns(item.Database);
    item.Fields[fieldName].Returns(field);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go into `ImageField.MediaItem` getter, you'll notice that the `MediaDatabase.GetItem()` method uses 3 parameters including language and version:

```
this.mediaItem = this.MediaDatabase.GetItem(mediaId, this.MediaLanguage, this.MediaVersion);
```

In your test you mock *another overload* of the `GetItem()` method that uses ID only:

```
database.GetItem(new ID("12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012")).Returns(mediaItem);
```

So, in order to pass this particular line, you have to update the GetItem call with smth like this (I assume it does not really matter in this scenario which language/version is used so we can use any):

```
database.GetItem(new ID("12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"),
    Arg.Any<Language>(), Version.Latest).Returns(mediaItem);
```

Comment: Thanks Serhii, that change has indeed allowed me to progress. I will update my question to show the adjusted code. Marking as accepted answer now.  

I have now discovered two further issues:  

_[1] The static call to  HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl() is throwing an exception_ => how would you normally deal with such calls? Would I move that into view or view model?  

_[2] my mocking of BaseMediaManager doesnt return any data_ => I will raise a follow up question for this